# How to switch to find files through 2nd project in Atom?

Tags: atom-editor

I opened a project "ProjectOne" in atom and then added another project folder "ProjectTwo". When I `cmd + t` to look for a folder, it always looks through ProjectOne even though I have that folder tree folded and ProjectTwo tree opened. How do I look through ProjectTwo and switch back and forth between the two projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Atom window has currently has one project. If the two folders are added to the same project (that is, they are both added in  the same Atom window), then the file fuzzy finder will search through files in both of them (because the fuzzy finder searches through the entire project, not just individual folders added to the project).

For now, if you want to search through individual root folders, you'll need to either open them in different Atom windows, or use a plugin that behaves the way you want it to.